# What is the difference between the preconfigured packages and the binaries

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, anchor

We have different options for installing the stellar-core and horizon specially. What is the difference and where shall a new user start to be able to configure a custom anchor?

Comment: Have you gone through this guide first? https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/

It may be easier to set up all of the things mentioned in the guide before trying to run stellar-core and your own Horizon API server.

Comment: Thanks, @kolten for the reply. Actually, yes I have done that. The thing is I need to setup a production-ready node with the core, horizon, compliance and bridge server. I am not yet sure how to set them up in the cloud environment.